# Using array as map key: impossible even with custom allocator?

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, stdmap, allocator

This question is related to [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582529/using-array-as-map-value-cant-see-the-error) [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19347049/error-array-used-as-initializer-and-i-dont-know-the-error) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200471/what-is-the-best-way-to-use-the-c-type-uuid-t-as-a-key-in-stl-stdmap).

I was trying to use a fixed-length array as a key to a `std::map`, as demonstrated in the non-compiling code below:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

typedef char myuuid[ 16 ];

template <class T>
class MyAlloc
{
public:
  typedef T value_type;
  typedef T* pointer;
  typedef T& reference;
  typedef const T* const_pointer;
  typedef const T& const_reference;
  template <class U> struct rebind { typedef MyAlloc<U> other; };
  MyAlloc() {}
  MyAlloc( const MyAlloc& other ) {}
  T* allocate( std::size_t n ) { return static_cast<T*>( std::malloc( n * sizeof( value_type ) ) ); }
  void deallocate( T* p, std::size_t n ) { std::free( p ); }
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  std::map<myuuid, int, std::less<myuuid>, MyAlloc<myuuid> > map;
  myuuid myu;
  map[ myu ] = 5;

  return 0;
}
```

Momentarily ignoring the custom allocator, if I correctly understand the linked answers, the reason that `std::map<myuuid, int> map; myuuid myu; map[myu] = 5;` fails comes down to the following being impossible:

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  char a[3];
  char b[3];
  b = a; // Illegal - won't compile
  return 0;
}
```

**Question**:

I understand why the above is illegal - but am I correct that this demonstrates the reason why `std::map<myuuid, int> map; myuuid myu; map[myu] = 5;` is illegal?

**Question**:

I thought I might be able to get away with compiling `std::map<myuuid, int> map; myuuid myu; map[myu] = 5;` if I implemented a custom allocator. I guessed that perhaps the `=` (assignment) of a `myuuid` would be "rerouted" to `MyAlloc::allocate()`, but that was a wild, unreasoned guess, which seems to be false. Is there a way that a custom allocator can be modified to solve the first code-block's compilation error?

I have a half-baked notion that that `operator=` on `myuuid` operands could be "rerouted" to the custom allocator, but I don't know if this is true for PODs (`myuuid` is just typedef'ed to a POD`).

The compile error is too voluminous to post here, but tellingly, the first error is:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8.3/bits/stl_pair.h: In instantiation of \u2018std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const _T1&, const _T2&) [with _T1 = const char [16]; _T2 = int]\u2019:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.3/bits/stl_map.h:469:59:   required from \u2018std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](const key_type&) [with _Key = char [16]; _Tp = int; _Compare = std::less<char [16]>; _Alloc = MyAlloc<char 
[16]>; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type = int; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = char [16]]\u2019
main.cpp:27:12:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8.3/bits/stl_pair.h:113:31: error: array used as initializer
       : first(__a), second(__b) { }
```

Interestingly, `error: array used as initializer` is the original compile error I was trying to solve from before introducing the custom allocator. So this seems like a recursive problem.

**Question**:

Can use of an array as a `std::map` key be pulled off somehow by making use of a custom allocator? (Perhaps there's an optional function I should implement?) Or are the alternatives at the noted links the only solutions? (It was not raised in the answers to those questions, but since custom allocators are a bit esoteric, I thought it was worth a separate question)

Comment: TL;DR but `typedef std::array<char, 16> myuuid;`

Comment: just use `std::array<char,16>` or `std::string`

Comment: @juanchopanza - thank you, I'm willing to accept that as an alternative, but wrt this question, I'm interested (out of the desire to understand/learn) if/how this could be solved with a custom allocator.

Comment: @StoneThrow Plain arrays are not copyable or assignable. That is part of the language, and can't be changed by an allocator.

Comment: @juanchopanza - "Plain arrays are not copyable or assignable" - so this means there's no way to override the `operator=` for a plain array in the way you can override it for non-POD - is that correct?

Comment: @StoneThrow It doesn't mean that, but that is also true.

Comment: @juanchopanza - Understood. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Raw C arrays are not well behaved types.  You cannot assign them or do a myriad of other things with them you'd want to.

Second, `std::less<char[16]>` doesn't work.

C++ provides `std::array`, which is a thin wrapper around a raw C array in a `struct`.

```
typedef std::array<char, 16> myuuid;
```

It even comes with a built in `<` that does the right thing usually.

So we get:

```
std::map<myuuid, int> map;
```

and things work.

`std::array` has `[]` and `.data()` and `.size()` and `.begin()` and `.end()` and generally behaves well.

If you need to convert it to a pointer, just call `.data()`.

Comment: @juanchopanza So it does.  I don't sort arrays often.